# implementing eCommerce tracking with separate class function

Tags: php

I'm trying to get Google's eCommerce tracking set up in a store website (never done this before) but I'm having issues running the script on each item in an order. The store's confirmation page pulls the script in from a class function. Here is the PHP that contains the eCommerce script for items:

```
function googleItems($items)
{
    $order = $this->getOrder($order_num);
    $count = count($items);
    if($count > 0)
    {
        for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++)
        {
            $return = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                          'id': ".$_GET['id'].",
                          'name': '".$items[$x]->title."',
                          'sku': '".$items[$x]->sku."',
                          'category': 'Bibles',
                          'price': ".$items[$x]->product_total.",
                          'quantity': ".$items[$x]->qty_ordered."
                        });
                        ga('ecommerce:send');
                    </script>
                    ";
        }
    return $return;
    }
}
```

When I visit the confirmation page that this script is supposed to run on, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type order_history as array in /thank-you.php on line 28
```

Which refers to the PHP that pulls in the above script:

```
$page['middle'] = "{$order->googleTransaction($_GET['id'])}
{$order->googleItems($order['items'])}
<div class='row'>
    <div class='twelve columns'>
        {$message}
    </div>
</div>";
```

I'm at a loss on how to fix this error.

Comment: It looks like `$items` isn't being passed in as an array, but rather an object of the `order_history` type.

Comment: Also, I think `$_GET->id` should be `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Oh right, I was using array syntax on each of the objects previously, before I changed to object property syntax using "->". I must have accidentally changed $_GET as well.